# 400 Bad Request on ajax post with @RequestBody using Jackson

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm getting 400 Bad Request on Ajax request when trying to map my JSON to a Java object in spring MVC controller. I have checked most of the relevant questions in the topic but still couldn't make it work

Ajax call and JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vocabulary/createVocabulary",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {"vocabularyName" : "a",
    "vocabularyDescription" : "b"},
```

My controller:

```
@Service
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="vocabulary")
public class VocabularyController {

@RequestMapping (path = "createVocabulary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody String createVocabulary(@RequestBody VocabularyDTO vocabularyDTO){
    return "Success";
  }
}
```

My Java object:

```
public class VocabularyDTO {

private String vocabularyName;
private String vocabularyDescription;

public VocabularyDTO(){};

public String getVocabularyName() {
    return vocabularyName;
}

public void setVocabularyName(String vocabularyName) {
    this.vocabularyName = vocabularyName;
}

public String getVocabularyDescription() {
    return vocabularyDescription;
}

public void setVocabularyDescription(String vocabularyDescription) {
    this.vocabularyDescription = vocabularyDescription;
}
}
```

I use Spring 4.2.5 and Jackson:

```
...

def springVersion = "4.2.5.RELEASE"

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}

dependencies {

compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-core", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-beans", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-context", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-aop", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-web", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-webmvc", version: "$springVersion"
compile group: "org.springframework.data", name: "spring-data-jpa", version: "1.9.4.RELEASE"

compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-databind", version: "2.6.5"
compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-core", version: "2.6.5"
compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-annotations", version: "2.6.5"

...
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> HTTP ERROR 400
>   Problem accessing /ux/vocabulary/createVocabulary. Reason:
>   BAD_REQUEST

Additionally, if I remove the '@RequestBody'annotation from my controller I get the following server response:

> Failed to instantiate [com.attila.vocabulary.ux.spring.vocabulary.DTO.VocabularyDTO]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.attila.vocabulary.ux.spring.vocabulary.DTO.VocabularyDTO.()

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE:
The option without '@RequestBody' annotation is actually working now (it was a silly mistake of mine why it didn't before) - i.e. not throwing error, however without the values being passed to the object.

I was hoping it would fix the annotation as well but I still get the 400 error that way.

Comment: There's no other error messages along with that 400?

Comment: Not that I know of - this is all I get as a response in the browser. Is there any way to find out more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working when using `@RequestBody` because your ajax request is not sending a json object. You need to serialise the JavaScript object before sending it, using JSON.stringify(). And why are you using `@Service` at your controller? Try with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vocabulary/createVocabulary",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({"vocabularyName" : "a",
    "vocabularyDescription" : "b"}),


@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="vocabulary")
public class VocabularyController {

@RequestMapping (path = "createVocabulary", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
@ResponseBody String createVocabulary(@RequestBody VocabularyDTO vocabularyDTO){
    return "Success";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The serialization helped. It's working correctly now.